# Default DataTemplate for a control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to make a property editor which would show different control for different data types.

For example if the data is a bool it should be a checkbox. If it is a color it should be a color picker. If it is an int it should be a numeric up down ect.

For everything else it should be a textbox <-- this is where im struggling.

for bool I can do

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mscorlib:Boolean}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=.}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

and this works perfectly.

But I can't figure out how to make the default textbox case happen.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock >
</DataTemplate>
```

would give me IDictionary must have a Key attribute error

If I adds a key to the template it won't be used unless I explicitly do something like `DataTemplate="..."`

I cant seem to find a way for the given template to target more than one type either. Which is forcing me to copy paste the template over and over for each type I wish to support.

Is there a better way to do it??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify a default empty DataTemplate instead of the default 'ToString()' DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709853/specify-a-default-empty-datatemplate-instead-of-the-default-tostring-datatem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using xaml style + converter.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyValue}" 
    <ContentPresenter.Style>
         <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
               <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                           <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                     <TextBox Text="Dead beef"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                           </Setter.Value>
                   </Setter>
               </Style.Setters>
         <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ToTypeConverter}}" Value="{x:Type mscorlib:Boolean}">
                      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                  <DataTemplate>
                                       <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                                  </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                      </Setter>
                 </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </ContentPresenter.Style>
</ContentPresenter>
```

converter

```
public class ToTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value == null) ? null : value.GetType();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The idea is to put the default template inside style's ContentTemplate and only modify the special ones using style trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Most professional way of doing this to use templateselector.

> Use the IntegerUpDown control in the xtended wpf toolkit for numeric
>   up and down
>
> Use the colorpicker control of xtended wpf toolkit for color picker

**Include this in xaml**

```
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"



          <DataTemplate x:Key="TEMPLATE">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="BOOLEANTEMPLATE">
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate x:Key="numericTemplate">
                       <xctk:IntegerUpDown Name="myUpDownControl" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate x:Key="ColorTemplate">
                        <xctk:ColorPicker></xctk:ColorPicker>
                    </DataTemplate>
                        <me:DynamicDataTemplateSelector        x:Key="datagridDynamictemplateselector"                                                     BooleanTemplate="{StaticResource BOOLEANTEMPLATE}"
ColorTemplate ="{StaticResource ColorTemplate}"
NumericTemplate ="{StaticResource numericTemplate}"
                                                        TextBoxTemplate="{StaticResource TEMPLATE}" />
```

**Here is the class which override datatemplateselector class**

```
  public class DynamicDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
        {
            public DataTemplate TextBoxTemplate{get;set;}
            public DataTemplate BooleanTemplate{get;set;}

            public DataTemplate NumericTemplate { get; set; }
            public DataTemplate ColorTemplate { get; set; }
            public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
            {
                DataTemplate dataTemplate = TextBoxTemplate;
                  if(item!=null)
                  {                  
                      Type dataTypeOfValue = item.GetType();

                        if(dataTypeOfValue==typeof(int))
                       {
                           dataTemplate = NumericTemplate;
                       }
                       else if(dataTypeOfValue==typeof(Color))
                       {
                           dataTemplate = ColorTemplate;
                       }

                       else if (dataTypeOfValue == typeof(Boolean) || dataTypeOfValue == typeof(bool))
                        {
                            dataTemplate = BooleanTemplate;
                        }

                  }
                 return dataTemplate;
            }
```

Comment: while this might work. There are a couple things I would like to point out. You don't need UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. You don't need item.GetType(). if (item is bool) would work. you don't need to check both bool and Boolean since one is just an alias of another. And you can simplify the code by calling FrameworkElement .FindResource(templateName)

Comment: Textbox by default has updated source trigger set to lost focus so that's why I changed it to property changed. We should not depend on resource name because if you change it in xaml and forgot to change in the overridden class you will get a runtime exception which will lead to wastage of time.Commercial WPF control use this approach.